# How can I fix the lag in displaying a text field when pressing a button in my React app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am getting started with React and doing a simple app. Basically when pressing a button it should generate some random-ish data (for simulating trade in a RPG). It seems to pretty much work except the last text field, which should only contain text when the generated resources is Wine/Brandy: it should display the quality of it.

The problem is that the quality never shows when Wine/Brandy is generated (instead of say Timber) but will show when I press the Generate button again, no matter the type of resource. So it seems to be lagging behind.

After some investigation I am guessing it has to with the asynchronous nature of States but I can't seem to make it work.

I'll try to make a condensed version of the code.

```
const [resourcesIndex, setResourcesIndex] = useState(-1);
const [wineQualityIndex, setWineQualityIndex] = useState(-1);

function _generate(localCityIndex: int, localSeasonIndex: int ) {
    _rollCargo(getRandomInt(100));
    const currentWineQualityIndex = getRandomInt(6)-1;
    setWineQualityIndex(resourcesIndex == 5 ? currentWineQualityIndex : -1);
  }

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.saveAreaViewContainer}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#FFF" barStyle="dark-content" />
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        <ScrollView>
            <Button
              title="Generate"
              onPress={() => _generate(cityIndex, seasonIndex)}
            />
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>
              {resourcesIndex == -1 ? 'No resources' : resources[resourcesIndex]}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>
              {wineQualityIndex == -1 ? '' : 'The wine/brandy is of ' + wineQuality[wineQualityIndex] + ' quality'}
            </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

I have tried changing the way I update the different states but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you should pay attention to.

1. React batch updating. React by default tries to batch all the updates in a function or a block of code, so if any state update waiting for some promise to resolve may also cause other states also to not update. You might also want to check out - https://blog.bitsrc.io/automatic-batching-in-react-18-what-you-should-know-d50141dc096e
2. React state update works in async fashion. If you want to update some DOM element immediately, prefer using ref to the doc and directly use DOM APIs to apply the update.